# Distnoted terminal message

Tags: terminal, catalina, cpu, macos

I booted my Mac in Verbose Mode (command v) to see a live report for when my Mac is booting up. There, I found a “message in the bottle”, evidently left there by an Apple developer:

`(com.apple.disnoted.xpc.agent) <Notice>: This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.`

Distnoted provides “distributed notification services”. Distnoted is a perfectly benign process, but it can occasionally consume resources and make your Mac slow down, which is evidenced by multiple threads in Apple discussion forums linking CPU intensive processes to Distnoted.

If anyone could explain to me why the function needs to be constantly running (as opposed to when triggered by an incoming notification), what makes it resource intensive (my first impression is that notifications shouldn’t take up much CPU), and suggest ways how to optimize the resource usage.

*Mac mini, macOS 10.15*

Comment: We’re not a good place to ask - hey what’s your opinion on this. See the what not to ask part of the help in case you get some questions voted closed. Editing them to show your research and ask a practical question usually helps to reopen and get excellent answers that help everyone.

Comment: In this case, have you measured distnoted CPU usage? I have perfectly behaved systems idle and logging millions of notice messages like this daily.

Comment: I disagree, I think it’s practical because if you search Apple discussion forums, many threads have complaints about slow Macs related to distnoted. I ask for opinions because it’s a developer forum and such people might have insight into how to improve this agent - because obviously it’s not a defect per sé, but the function is not optimal.

Comment: Keep in mind - we are not a discussion forum.  This is a focused question and answer site.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I now reformulated my question to be more specific.

Comment: I’ll take a stab with an answer. Not sure how technical you want to get... there’s not much you would optimize here as the system is already designed and there’s no resource problem to be solved that I can see from your edited question.

Comment: Nothing like a Terminal command to run, or a script or patch to install?

Answer (score 0):

Distnoted is a daemon and it’s designed to run on demand since you see the [XPC framework is being invoked.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW6-SW1)

This is a [wonderfully technical part of operating system design](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794). Some of the best and accessible writing on why things run, how they run and why this can be very lightweight and efficient despite logging hundreds or thousands of messages is described here by Apple.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html

From a overall health perspective, you choose what apps run and how many notifications they generate, so the work assigned to this process only happens when you have notifications to deliver and it can idle otherwise.

To optimize your experience, you can log out and terminate all user apps and processed from terminal - `sudo launchctl reboot userspace` and then validate the daemon is idle by ssh back in to watch the CPU with `top -u -s 10` and `ps -ef | grep distnote[d]`